# Restart Tomcat using azure cli/cli2

Tags: azure-cli2

I'm trying to restart Tomcat server hosted on a Docker container using Azure CLI. What is the best approach to do that. I saw that I could do it running a .sh/powershel script via Azure CLI. Is there a better solution to restart the Tomcat?

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: Where do you run the Tomcat server hosted on a Docker container? Azure container instance? Azure VM? AKS? Please give more details about the host.

Answer (score 0):

It's unrelated to Azure CLI.

You can try to use Tomcat Host Manager API to stop and start a virtual host, if you have configured manager application access for your Tomcat in Docker, please see the Tomcat offical document [`Host Manager App -- Text Interface`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/host-manager-howto.html) to know more details.

The restart operation for Tomcat includes two steps of doing `stop` and `start` commands, as the figure below.

[image]

It is supported by [`HostManagerServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/manager/host/HostManagerServlet.html), as the figure below.

[image]

Hope it helps.